# on adding the other products to cart, the price and name of product picked is the first one

Tags: javascript

```js
const buyBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btnBuy');
const itemDesc = document.querySelector('.detail');
const priceDesc = document.querySelector('.price');




for (let counter = 0; counter < buyBtn.length; counter++) {
  buyBtn[counter].addEventListener('click', function() {
    getPrice()
  })
}

const getPrice = function() {
  const getPrice = function() {
    const prices = priceDesc.textContent
    console.log(prices);
  }
  getPrice()

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

.items-1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.items-2 {
  margin-top: -397px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items-1">
  <img id="one" src="images/shoe chair.jpg" width="250px" height="300px" alt="">
  <div class="desc">
    <label class="detail">Antique Sofa</label> <br><br>
    <label class="price">$500</label><br><br>
    <input class="btnBuy" type="button" value="Buy">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="items-2">
  <img id="one" src="images/princess.jpg" width="250px" height="300px" alt="">
  <div class="desc">
    <label class="detail">Princess</label> <br><br>
    <label class="price">$700</label><br><br>
    <input class="btnBuy" type="button" value="Buy">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: enter code here

Comment: Please may you add a clear problem description? And also more information helping others help you solve the issue.

Comment: if you click the button, the first item is picked or rather added to the console.log but on clicking the other button the first item is logged to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
const buyBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btnBuy');
for (const buyBtn of buyBtns) {
  buyBtn.addEventListener('click', getPrice);
}
function getPrice(event){
    const parent = event.target.parentElement;
    const itemDesc = parent.querySelector('.detail');
    const priceDesc = parent.querySelector('.price');
    const prices = priceDesc.textContent;
    console.log({itemDesc,priceDesc,prices});
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend it's working any tips where i can get more materials on javascript?